# Selenium won't find a <p:calendar> day by using By.linkText()

Tags: java, selenium, primefaces

While trying to execute a few tests using Selenium, it seems that it doesn't find the days in the pop-up calendar to click on them.

Calendar code.

```
p:calendar id="fechaSalida" value="#{trip.departureDate}" required="true"
                            pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss">
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{controllerTrips.alterDate}"
                            readonlyInput="true"
                            update="@all" />
                        </p:calendar>
```

Selenium test code.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("31")); 
    element.click();
```

or

```
    WebElement number = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("31")));
    number.click();
```

Comment: `By.linkText` needs an `<a>` tag. Do you have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use xpath: `By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '31')]")`

or if you need the p:calender you could use `By.id("fechaSalida")`